# How do I make a Karma compliant test harness for the browser?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

My guess is that the Karma test runner does not hook in Mocha and Jasmine, rather the reverse.

so I assume Mocha and Jasmine call something like this:

```
window.__karma__.testCasePassed(data);
window.__karma__.testCaseFailed(data);
```

and then Karma will report these events.

I am writing [Suman](https://github.com/sumanjs/suman) and I want to figure out if I can make Suman Karma compliant.

When I look through the Mocha and Jasmine codebase however, I am not seeing the evidence I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find anything in the code of Mocha or Jasmine themselves as they don't know anything about Karma. When you use Mocha and Jasmine in Karma you have to use [`karma-mocha`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha) and [`karma-jasmine`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine). *These* are the packages that bridge Mocha and Jasmine on the one hand, and Karma on the other.

If you look at `karma-mocha`, you'll see that it has a function called [`createMochaReporterConstructor`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha/blob/e847121e35f59a498c3b09f87f138621b550629b/src/adapter.js#L83-L174) which creates a Mocha reporter that calls function on `window.__karma__`. (You can see it called [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha/blob/e847121e35f59a498c3b09f87f138621b550629b/src/adapter.js#L216) and the first argument is `window.__karma__`.)

There is a bit of documentation about the Karma framework API on [this page](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/dev/plugins.html) (search for "Karma Framework API" to get to it). It is a very brief description though. If it were me, I'd look at the code of `karma-mocha` and `karma-jasmine` to have a better idea of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks @Louis - one thing I haven't figured out yet -  how does Karma know that the tests are complete and how it knows whether the process should exit with code 0 or not. There only seems to be a start hook, but no end hook.

Comment: As described in the API doc: calling `.complete` indicates that all tests have run. And I suspect Karma decides to exit with a code of 0 or not depending on what data was passed for `.result`, which must be called for each test to report whether the test passed or not. If one call to `.result` indicates a failure, then exit with a code other than 0.

Comment: ahhh nice, that's great thanks - I see that here: https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/dev/plugins.html

Comment: What's weird though is that karma doesn't exit...i guess in dev mode it watches and in production mode it will exit with the appropriate code.